# Text gets blur when using translate property in css

Tags: html, css

I have one section which has an image & some text. 
What I want is to hover over a div and it should show little rise animation effect on the div itself. 
It's working, but while the animation is playing, I've noticed that the text gets a little size change.

```css
.box-cards {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
            min-height:140px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
 }
 
 img{width:300px; height:200px;}
 
 .box-cards:hover{
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
                transform: scale(1.05);
                -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
                transition: all .3s ease;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<div class="box-cards">
        <div class="box-image">
            <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/660/1*WgROsTKa6diRYTG5K0R5mw.jpeg" class="img-responsive post-image" />
        </div>
    
        <div class="box-content">
            <h3>Hello there</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: share `html` code also

Comment: show working fiddle please

Comment: @Dr.Strange updated post with demo

Answer (score 0):

add hover styles to box-image instead of box-cards, check below

Styles

```
.box-cards {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
                min-height:140px;
                margin-bottom:20px;
                -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
                transition: all .3s ease;
     }

     img{width:300px; height:200px;}

     .box-image:hover{
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
                    transform: scale(1.05);
                    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
                    transition: all .3s ease;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
```

Dom

```
   <div class="box-cards">
            <div class="box-image">
                <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/660/1*WgROsTKa6diRYTG5K0R5mw.jpeg" class="img-responsive post-image" />
            </div>
                 <div class="box-content">
                <h3>Hello there</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Won't work. I ant entire section to have Rise effect not only image

Answer (score 0):

try this

use `.box-image` instead of `.box-card:hover`

```css
.box-cards {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  min-height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box-image:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-cards">
  <div class="box-image">
    <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/660/1*WgROsTKa6diRYTG5K0R5mw.jpeg" class="img-responsive post-image" />
  </div>

  <div class="box-content">
    <h3>Hello there</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Won't work. I ant entire section to have Rise effect not only image

Comment: so when image was zoom effect so text also zoom effect you cant anything in that..@SUN

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `.box-cards img:hover` instead of `.box-cards:hover`

```css
.box-cards {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
            min-height:140px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
 }
 
 img{width:300px; height:200px;}
 
 .box-cards img:hover{
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
                transform: scale(1.05);
                -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
                transition: all .3s ease;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<div class="box-cards">
        <div class="box-image">
            <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/660/1*WgROsTKa6diRYTG5K0R5mw.jpeg" class="img-responsive post-image" />
        </div>
    
        <div class="box-content">
            <h3>Hello there</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Won't work. I ant entire section to have Rise effect not only image

Comment: If you want entire div, the text will also enlarge look alike image because of your zoom effect. If you want the text same size, just add the effect on the image.